# is it possible to recover unsaved google colab notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, recovery

probably hopeless but trying my luck here anyway.

i was working on google colab for some school project. finished most of it but didn't save because there was some error (saw red sign stating it wasn't saved)

i didn't bother myself because i leave the computer open.

today i was going back to work on it when suddenly i notice the notebook reverted automatically to it's last checkpoint which (due to that error i ignored) was from over ten days ago.

is there anything i can do about it?

seems really not fair...
):

Comment: Do you have the error screenshot?

Comment: no just red font fail to save (something like this)

Comment: @enter_thevoid did you try coming to the project file you are working on and then clicking the "File" --> "Revision History" part?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me tonight and the result of a week's work day and night was lost.
You can't do anything. Although it is not fair, if the saving is not done automatically and the codes are not saved in Google Drive, you cannot do anything.
I'm telling you this while I'm having a stroke from frustration and shock and an hour of searching for a solution

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33638248)